# How to set font size in percent so that different browsers would render it same?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

I'm designing a website and I've met with an interesting problem. I've designed my font-size for different media, using syntax like this:

```
   @media all and (max-width:1100px) {html {font-size:109%;transition:1s;}}
```

Everything renders and looks fine when using Chrome. Now I've tried to check it on FireFox, just to be safe and I saw, that same CSS rule is being rendered larger in one zoom level (If is click ctrl+- once then ir renders correctly, if I reset zoom to normal state - text is bigger again).

Should I be creating CSS media rules for FF exclusively or there is some standard way to make this work?

CSS reset is applied and doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: Try to use relative units, ie. "rem" or "em"

Comment: @MightyPork — `%` **is** a relative unit. `100% === 1em`.

Comment: I suspect we'll need to see some more of the code to help figure this one out. Have you set a base `font-size` on `body`?

Comment: Thank you @OllyHodgson setting font-size on body helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was no base font-size on body. So the problem was fixed by simply setting this base size equal to 100%.

Thanks to Olly Hodgson who pointed this out.